# How can I take multiple integer input from scanner and store each integer in separate arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a program which allows the user to addition as many pairs of numbers as they would like, by first taking user input to ask them how many sums they would like to complete (additions of 2 numbers), thereafter creating 2 arrays of whatever size the user has input, and then asking the user to input each pair of numbers on a single line that they would like to addition and storing the first value in one array and the second value in a second array from each input. This is where I am stuck, I don't know how I can take the user input as two int values on each line and store them in the respective indexes of each array to be added later. Please take a look at my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumsInLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of sums you would like to calculate: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    int a[] = new int[n];
    int b[] = new int[n];

    String[] input = new String[2];
    System.out.println("Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            int[] intinput = Arrays.asList(input).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
a = intinput[0];
b = intinput[1];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using nextLine() method, which is useful for string input, but it's not the best solution for integer or other primitive data.

In addition, this line of code is wrong :

```
a = intinput[0];
```

because you're storing an integer value as integer array.
You must store that value inside a[i] in order to respect the variables type.

I'd do it this way:

```
public class SumsInLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of sums you would like to calculate: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int a[] = new int[n];
        int b[] = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: ");
            // Read pair and store it inside i-th position of a and b arrays 
            System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
            b[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        // Close scanner
        sc.close();

        // Prints every sum
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            System.out.println(i + "-th sum is: " + (a[i] + b[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Here you read every pair with nextInt() which is specific for integer data.

Every time you store items in i-th position of arrays, so finally you can sum `a[i]` and `b[i]`.

Result example:

```
Enter the amount of sums you would like to calculate: 
4
Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: 
Enter first number: 
2
Enter second number: 
1
Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: 
Enter first number: 
3
Enter second number: 
4
Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: 
Enter first number: 
5
Enter second number: 
6
Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: 
Enter first number: 
7
Enter second number: 
8
0-th sum is: 3
1-th sum is: 7
2-th sum is: 11
3-th sum is: 15
```

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler than I thought! I thought I would have to use a nested loop to take values from each position in the two arrays to add each integer together. Thank you for your time and efforts to help me in reaching a solution.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them.  It doesn't help them in the long run.  Give them hints that allow to work it out for themselves.  And in this case, you don't explain why the OPs original solution is wrong.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer with more details. In reality I just fixed a little his code which was almost correct, but thank you for your suggestion, I'll change my approach for future answer :)

Comment: It wasn't my homework, just a problem I was trying to solve to improve my programming skills. :)

Comment: @Spartan123 - Actually, it makes no difference whether it was homework or a self-directed learning exercise.  The same principle applies.  You learn more by doing it yourself.  (And I wasn't having a go at you for asking.  I was criticising the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change 2 lines this way:

```
a[i] = intinput[0];
b[i] = intinput[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read pairs with `nextInt()` method of scanner, it's use all space symbols like separator (not only end of line):

```
public class SumsInLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of sums you would like to calculate: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int a[] = new int[n];
        int b[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Please enter the values you would like to sum as pairs of two numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            b[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them. It doesn't help them in the long run. Give them hints that allow to work it out for themselves.